# Is it possible to turn an R incidence object to a dataframe and use this for plotting?

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis

Is it possible to convert an incidence object into a dataframe and then somehow use this for plotting? The reason I need to do this is because I have to export a file in CSV format out of a secure server (incidence objects not allowed and raw data not allowed - but monthly/weekly counts fine) and generate the plot outside of the server. E.g:

```
library(outbreaks)
library(ggplot2)
library(incidence)

dat <- ebola_sim$linelist$date_of_onset
i <- incidence(dat)
plot(i)

i_df <- as.data.frame(i)
```

Is there a way to generate the same plot using the raw data in the "i_df" dataframe? Can it be turned back into an incidence object for example?

Comment: could you share dput(dat)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `incidence:::incidence.plot()` function is basically a wrapper around `ggplot()/geom_col()`.. For your specific example dataset, you can basically do

```
ggplot(i_df, aes(dates,counts)) + geom_col(width=1)
```

to replicate the basic content of the output of `plot(i)`; for full replication, you can then update the labels, axis, etc.

As to your second question, you can recover the equivalent `incidence` object from `i_df`, by doing this:

```
incidence(rep(i_df$dates, i_df$counts))
```

If you have created an incidence object using the `groups` parameter, the recovery approach is similar, but you have to treat each of the groups separately (if there are lots of groups, I would suggest some kind of loop structure). Example, when groups=gender

```
# creation of grouped incidence object
i.sex <- incidence(ebola_sim$linelist$date_of_onset, groups = ebola_sim$linelist$gender)

# conversion to data.frame
i.sex_df = as.data.frame(i.sex)

# recovery back to an equivalent incidence object
incidence(
  c(rep(i.sex_df$dates, i.sex_df$f),rep(i.sex_df$dates, i.sex_df$m)),
  groups = c(rep("f",sum(i.sex_df$f)), rep("m",sum(i.sex_df$m)))
)
```

Comment: any idea how to recover the incidence object if you have set a "group"? e.g.
```
i.sex <- incidence(onset, interval = 7, group =  ebola_sim_clean$linelist$gender)
```

Comment: see edit for group wise recovery.. note that I did not have access to your `onset` or your `ebola_sim_clean` objects